# How can I add my own meta tags to BlueCore HTML Email Code Editor without jinja blocking my content attribute?

Tags: jinja2, html-email

I'm upgrading HTML Email templates in BlueCore.  For some genius reason they decided to block ***any*** html tags that have an attribute not listed in their pre-defined-allowed-attributes-list, which, is preventing the use of the following meta tag (among others) simply because they won't allow the use of an html attribute 'content' in *any of their emails*:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

The problem is that outside of Bluecore our email templates look perfect across all devices in litmus, and look good when they are sent with the proper meta tags!  BlueCore's bug-prone system is really throwing us for a loop, and their support takes days to get back, if at all regarding this "feature"...

I've been trying to piece together the needed meta tags, or even just the attribute it's blocking, by using macros, or string concatenation, without any luck so far using jinja...

Does anyone know of a way to do any of the following:

1. Dump a list of available scopes & scope variables
2. Piece together the meta tags using variables or strings, while getting the renderer to put them in to the header before it gets sent?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations to every system. Bluecore is no exception but they definitely block more than most.

1. The best practice to building HTML campaigns is to build the basic elements in a block template first, export the code and use that to frame your emails. The meta tag used on these campaigns are
   meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
   meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"

The reason you can't simply use any meta tag in their platform is this is connected to the platforms ability to render proofs. Bluecore's campaign system isn't set up to be compatible with the metatag your trying to generate. This would be an account template setting and they may not have the ability to customize it at this time.

2. Piecing a meta tag together won't change the ways its rendered. Its read the exact same way by the system.

While they have removed some of the most helpful documentation (eye roll) you can always set variables with jinja for example if your preaheader doesn't show up on mobile devices

```
{% set preheader='Enter Preview Text Here' %} can be appended to at the envelope level to update a hidden attribute within the template
{{preheader}}
```

You can also use Jinja to display cases for custom HTML blocks.

```
{% if customer.state == 'CA' %}
{% elif customer.state == 'NY' %}
{% endif %}
```